# Looking for a good book on groups and graph theory

Tags: graph-theory, book-recommendation, symmetric-groups, algebraic-graph-theory

Can anyone help me on which book would be best book to understand

Permutation groups how it represents graphs in graph theory and other with good simple examples and is much self explanatory

And dihedral groups how it represents graphs too

Orbits and stabilizer

In a very self explanatory way with examples relating it to graphs in graph theory with examples from basis

For a beginner

Kindly help by recommending a book that I can study as a beginner to learn algebra in graph theory of the above topic mainly permutation groups, orbits and stabilizer

Comment: I know abstract algebra like herstien and graph theory now I am looking books which can explain the relationship between permutation groups and all above with simple example so that it can help me understand

Comment: S exactly and also I need it with small examples for dihedral groups and orbits , stabilizer etc how in graph theory with very very simple graphs and small examples so that it will be easy for me understand and also find the number of unique permutation of a graph with simple example in self explanatory way and should be like a good teacher explaining. Even group of symmetries of a graph is also mean not exactly Cayley graphs

Comment: Then it seems better to talk to someone like a good teacher. Posting here will just give you references you can google yourself. Alternatively you could try to improve your question by asking something precise about an explicit example, like $D_5$.

Comment: S I need good book written who might have been the best written and great person in that who writes good book who is by himself be a great teacher because then only they can write a such a self explanatory book understanding students requirements. As I need to read a good book than posting each line as a question.  I tried in Google not able to may be good people here as all give us the best understanding the students requirements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you are looking for, but there is a field known as "Geometric Group Theory" where we study groups by their actions on graphs (and other things too).

> A fantastically approachable first reference (I'm biased, as it was my first reference) is Meier's "Groups, Graphs, and Trees".

As for how this pertains to your question, chapter 1 of this book discusses Cayley's Theorem (that every group is a subgroup of a symmetric group) and what is somewhat cheekily referred to as Cayley's Better Theorem (that every group is a group of symmetries of some graph). Chapter 1 also discusses the orbit-stabilizer theorem, as well as the dihedral groups (and how they act on graphs).

The entire book is wonderful, but already the first 2 chapters will discuss everything you have brought up in this question. It is filled with good exposition and fantastic pictures to help you see what's happening.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Great yes will check if any link for book kindly share too

Comment: You should be able to find it on the Library of Genesis, which you can Google

Comment: Found Graphs and Groups title one book for a starter like me

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - did you find a book you like?

Comment: S sir I found the book